# How to update formula property after insert in fluent nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have a class with a property that is using a formula:

```
CONCAT(code, CAST(id AS CHAR))
```

When I insert a instance with

```
_session.Save(x);
```

The formula is still null, but Id is updated.

How can i make sure the formula gets updated when I insert something?